# RFID Reader Using OTG input

Tags: android, android-edittext, keyboard-events, rfid

I am using OTG RFID Reader for Android.
It's working fine in Edittext or Input text while swapping card.

Basically Micro USB RFID Reader which is Keyboard Interface.

So I wanted to know can i use this without Edittext.

I am currently doing Edittext using 1dp width and 1 dp for height,
and transparent background as well as text color.

I am looking for some kind of service solution which give me data when io system recive data. That means before show to edit text.

Comment: have you tried implementing dispatchKeyEvent?
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#dispatchKeyEvent%28android.view.KeyEvent%29

Comment: No not yet let me try dispatchKeyEvent

Comment: did the solution work?

Comment: please accept an answer if it helped you

Comment: I tired Its working with DispatchKeyEvent . Thank SoroushaA

Comment: glad to help. Please accept the answer below as the correct answer if it helped you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture any key event without having an EditText. You need to implement `dispatchKeyEvent` in your activity to capture each `KeyEvent`. You can then send them to a service in the background to be processed (for example send out an event when a full RFID is scanned or when the number of scanned events reach a certain number or however else you want to use them).

[dispatchKeyEvent documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#dispatchKeyEvent%28android.view.KeyEvent%29)